# Hibernate Join Query not working

Tags: hibernate

I have to Table namely employee and department
In Department table

```
CREATE TABLE `department` (
`department_id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`dept_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`department_id`));
```

In Emplyee table

```
CREATE TABLE `employee` (
`employee_id` BIGINT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`firstname` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`lastname` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`birth_date` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`department_id` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`employee_id`),
INDEX `FK_DEPT` (`department_id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_DEPT` FOREIGN KEY (`department_id`) REFERENCES `department` (`department_id`));
```

I want to display Employee first name, last name, and their department name 
So how can I write a query into hibernate Please help

Comment: Something like `from Employee e inner join e.department`, depending on your code.  Have you tried something yet?

Comment: Can you please post the code you have tried to solve the problem with?

Comment: FROM Employee AS e , Department AS d WHERE e.employee_id = d.department and d.dept_name = :deptname